# Why is my custom HTML Helper result getting html encoded?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html-encode

I've got the following custom html helper in asp.net mvc 3

```
public static string RegisterJS(this HtmlHelper helper, ScriptLibrary scriptLib)
{
   return "<script type=\"text/javascript\"></script>\r\n";
}
```

The problem is that the result is getting html encoded like so (I had to add spaces to get so to show the result properly:

```
   &lt;script type=&quot;text/javascript&quot;&gt;&lt;/script&gt;
```

This obviously isn't much help to me.. Nothing I've read says anything about this.. any thoughts on how I can get my real result back?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You're calling the helper in a Razor `@` block or an ASPX `<%: %>` block.
These constructs automatically escape their output.

You need to change the helper to return an `HtmlString`, which will not be escaped:

```
return new HtmlString("<script ...");
```

Comment: Thanks.  Is this a change in 3? Even the MS example I found just returned string..

Comment: @Shane: No; it's a feature of the view engine.

Comment: You might be looking at an example from MVC1. In MVC 2 all helpers got changed to return an HtmlString so that the ASPX auto-encoding feature from .NET 4 could work (using `<%: %>` instead of `<%= %>`). The new Razor view engine automatically encodes everything.